# Java Application won`t play sound

Tags: java, audio, netbeans, playsound

I wrote a program to play a bird sound. I got no errors when launching it but there was no sound. I'm running Netbeans IDE. Any ideas or solutions?

Here is my code:

```
package JavaFactoryPatternExample;


import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class TutorialSound {
public static void main(String[] args ){
    File Bird = new File("JavaFactoryPatternExample.sounds/bird.WAV");
    PlaySound(Bird);
}

 static void PlaySound(File Sound){
    try{
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
        clip.start();

        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Replace that empty catch block with something that **prints** errors; and then add that to your question. Maybe your file path is wrong; or something else. There are many possible explanations; and most likely, just looking at that currently suppressed error message will tell you that.

Comment: I will try that, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the file is in the same directory as the java program and that you have named it correctly. The file name seems odd.

Comment: Can i just drop the bird.wav file directly into my project folder or do i have to make an external folder "sounds" for it? :)

Comment: go ahead and put it in the project folder, see what happens. If the file is in the same directory as the java file, you don't have to worry about including the absolute path.